# How do I control exporting a shapefile to KML by a specific attribute?

Tags: qgis, kml, google-earth, mmqgis

I am working in QGIS with a very large file - over 10,000 records, sorted into 1100+ groupings. It needs to be exported to KML and display in Google Earth - I'm using MMGIS to do this. I would like it to show up in Google Earth in clusters of groupings (so all the 1's together, 2's, and so on).

Prior to export, I have ordered my attribute file so that these groupings are correct, noting that I will have to go back and change the string to a numeric value.

[image: Attribute Table QGIS]

However, when I export the file to KML and open it in Google Earth, it is consistently losing the groupings:

[image: KML File in Google Earth]

I am looking for a way to control the KML export so that I keep the groupings together.